# How to add values near names of the nodes in ECharts (Sankey)

Tags: echarts, sankey-diagram

I am creating a Sankey Chart in EChart and I need to have values be shown near the names of nodes (in labels). So could you help me - how to change the code for that? GPT failed to help me. It only shows values when you take a mouse to it.

```
{
    "title": {
        "text": "Zodiac - Gender - Hobby",
        "subtext": "et",
        "left": "center",
        "top": "top"
    },
    "tooltip": {
        "trigger": "item",
        "triggerOn": "mousemove"
    },
    "animation": false,
    "series": [
        {
            "type": "sankey",
            "emphasis": {
                "focus": "adjacency"
            },
            "nodeAlign": "justify",
            "orient": "horizontal",
            "data": [
                {
                    "name": "Male"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Run"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Basketball"
                },
                {
                    "name": "Football"
                }
            ],
            "links": [
                {
                    "source": "Male",
                    "target": "Run",
                    "value": 56
                },
                {
                    "source": "Male",
                    "target": "Basketball",
                    "value": 24
                },
                {
                    "source": "Male",
                    "target": "Football",
                    "value": 77
                }
            ],
            "lineStyle": {
                "color": "source",
                "curveness": 0.5
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [label formatter function](https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-sankey.label.formatter):

```js
series: [{
    label: {
        formatter: '{b}: {c}'
    }
}]
```

[Here](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=line-simple&code=PYBwLglsB2AEC8sDeAoWtJgDYFMBcya6GOAHmAQOQBawAJhAIYDGsAtLAOI7R04BO7WAAlgAIzEBPSgBoi6AM4BXMWDIVYlHGFnzYuAGYbKzHmv67iGUFTChKRAL5z0d4FkggCqK2H4QAcwCBKgg1AFtLYj9A4P4AeWgqcOAlBRwUgDccB3RnIkZoCHDGSBgCA0YsdJdYdP8cBQIAbT0fKwxJEHxNBUKAaxxpWqsMkAALRgUIJsIO4gNgZjSqRjoAKxYeZmk9PJHiaHocAEEsQKTNdbTIA2G92GAG6GNxp4gALxgwKqirOlKjBaD3Q7Xm6GgjHCPUoAFkqjkQbB8uC5qjYJDoVQAEpKaC5cEo8Fg8GYmEAISmgzAYiqWAJ8yJ8xJ8zJVAAYsBgDS6QyOo4HgBdA7oc7QfqzVqolkdBSpfimKjw3B_cE_fjBYy4_EijqZKpKHoAVgAbEimR0ZVY5UoFTDlTldb5GBrtFRKQpqbSsPSncR9VhDQQAEwAFnNfqtxBtdqVCNV83Vmo5XJ5PoTeoNPQA7NnzULdWKcABlMCSXDeJHMdxPKgx0wZ9DLfjZaCNWYABgAdEaHhbRYwxDgsJXUYt-CUwOYqEgxI5vMxHHy8noBehBShHABuIA) is a quick example.